# Overiding CSS. Is it better to override or recall all attributes

Tags: css

Is it better to do this:

```
.message_bookmark {
  display: block; 
  height: 40px; 
  width: 40px; 
  position: relative; 
  left: 540px; 
  top: -168px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.message_delete {   
  display: block; 
  height: 40px; 
  width: 40px;  
  position: relative; 
  left: 600px; 
  top: -128px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

or this:

```
.message_bookmark, .message_delete {
  display: block; 
  height: 40px; 
  width: 40px; 
  position: relative; 
  left: 540px; 
  top: -168px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.message_delete {   
  left: 600px; 
  top: -128px;
}
```

In terms of readability the second method is better suited and also uses less code, so which is actually best?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the the CSS subclass strategy similar to what you see in Twitter Bootstrap.

**CSS**

```
/*Base Class*/
.message{
  display: block; 
  height: 40px; 
  width: 40px; 
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5; 
}

/*Subclass*/
.message_bookmark{ 
  left: 540px; 
  top: -168px;
}

/*Subclass*/
.message_delete {   
  left: 600px; 
  top: -128px;
}
```

**HTML Usage**

```
<div class="message message_bookmark">BookMark</div>
<div class="message message_delete">BookMark</div>
```

Comment: Though I prefer this my self I always tell others: Just don't do it like Bootstrap which contains a lot of messed up stuff ;) Keep it clean and simple and it cannot go wrong. Also, this keeps the code at fewer lines.

Comment: @Daniel I like this style and picked it up from the SMACSS book: http://smacss.com/ It seems to make things simple and helps you handle the one off scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the second is better. Less code and like you say, more readable. Functionally the same so there's little point in repeating stuff.